# Mage sales order ::loadByIncrementId does not load order

Tags: magento-1.9, orders

What could go wrong if i load an order like:

```
// $val gets its value from controller (content type json utf8)
// json decoded file_get_contents('php://input') 
// then a anonymous function gets $val and loads an order:
$val = trim((string)$val);
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($val);
```

`$val` is an inrement id like 5000001.

Weird think is: some ids work, some not. But those who dont work exists.

What could go wrong by loading an order by model sales/order ?

**EDIT**

It was a **ZERO WITH SPACE** in the order increment id - see http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

I can advice to enable Magento logs and check if some logs will appear at var/log/ folder.

If not - you can also try to debug loading process at `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract`:

Find function

```
public function load(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object, $value, $field = null)
```

and try to put

```
echo $select->__toString();
```

after

```
$select = $this->_getLoadSelect($field, $value, $object);
```

then you should see mysql query which executed to load your order. Try to apply this query directly to database to see what's wrong with it